# SCORM : Developing SCORM player using ASP.NET MVC c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scorm, tin-can-api, scorm1.2, lms

I am at the initial stage of developing a **SCORM player** using **MVC ASP.Net**. How to use SCORM in ASP.Net MVC.
Please provide some assistance in developing the player on MVC Website. I also need help on the Integrating part.
The following sample was taken from the web and it's working fine. I need to integrate this using ASP.NET MVC.

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs
/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var API = {};

    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setupScormApi()

            $('#content').attr('src', 
     "file:///E:/Projects/SCORM/Sample/SCORM%20- 
    %20Storyline%20output/story.html")
        });

        function setupScormApi() {
            API.LMSInitialize = LMSInitialize;
            API.LMSGetValue = LMSGetValue;
            API.LMSSetValue = LMSSetValue;
            API.LMSCommit = LMSCommit;
            API.LMSFinish = LMSFinish;
            API.LMSGetLastError = LMSGetLastError;
            API.LMSGetDiagnostic = LMSGetDiagnostic;
            API.LMSGetErrorString = LMSGetErrorString;
        }

        function LMSInitialize(initializeInput) {
            displayLog("LMSInitialize: " + initializeInput);
            return true;
        }

        function LMSGetValue(varname) {
            displayLog("LMSGetValue: " + varname);
            return "";
        }

        function LMSSetValue(varname, varvalue) {
            displayLog("LMSSetValue: " + varname + "=" + 
       varvalue);
            return "";
        }

        function LMSCommit(commitInput) {
            displayLog("LMSCommit: " + commitInput);
            return true;
        }

        function LMSFinish(finishInput) {
            displayLog("LMSFinish: " + finishInput);
            return true;
        }

        function LMSGetLastError() {
            displayLog("LMSGetLastError: ");
            return 0;
        }

        function LMSGetDiagnostic(errorCode) {
            displayLog("LMSGetDiagnostic: " + errorCode);
            return "";
        }

        function LMSGetErrorString(errorCode) {
            displayLog("LMSGetErrorString: " + errorCode);
            return "";
        }

        function displayLog(textToDisplay) {
            var loggerWindow = 
   document.getElementById("logDisplay");
            var item = document.createElement("div");
            item.innerText = textToDisplay;
            loggerWindow.appendChild(item);
            var height = $('#logDisplay')[0].scrollHeight;
            $('#logDisplay').scrollTop(height);
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body style="display: flex; flex-direction: inherit; align-items: 
center; justify-content: center">
<iframe id="content" name="content" style="border: 1px solid 
blue; flex: 11; align-self: stretch" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<div id="logDisplay" style="flex: 1; align-self: stretch; border: 
1px solid red; padding: 5px;    overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```